# Percentage of high-rep users over time?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, data-explorer, high-rep-users, stack-exchange-history

I've thought of a SEDE project that would be very interesting, but I think it would require a time machine, and unfortunately my flux capacitor is busted. I'd like to know what the percentage of high-rep (let's say 10K+) users looked like at StackOverflow over time. At the beginning, of course, there are none; and the longer the site exists, the longer folks have to accrue reputation. But there are more users all the time... it's complex. Has anybody looked at this data, for SO or for any other SE site?

The stimulus for this was watching obvious dupes be multiply-answered today, and wondering where all the high-rep users are to close them. It makes me wonder if the percentage has peaked and is now on a decline.

Comment: This can still be done via the SEDE if you use a sub-query that recalcs reputation. If you put a time-restriction on those, you can (approximately) recalc the rep of any user (or all users at once) for any specific moment of time accurate to 1 day.

Comment: Cool, I did not know that! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My SQL isn't good enough to write a query that will efficiently generate a graph of the # of 10k users over time. But here's for starters:

Here's a small query that will generate the top users list for a specific point in time.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/123205/top-users-at-a-specific-date?DaysSinceLaunch=365

From here it should be fairly easy to count the # of 10k+ users. Which will be good enough for probing the # of 10k users at any one point of time.

---

The query isn't perfect since it doesn't include all possible reputation changes. But it should be fairly accurate for high-rep users.